# Can i disable hamburger in shell

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

if you can help me please answer this post please
I Use shell in my xaml page but i dont need hamburger in tittle view
if you know how to disable this please answer me
[Photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11MK06Ry7wNTpWmWvWOGzJqD3dlJn18L-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi , if answer be helpful ,remember to mark it . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4):

You can set [Flyout behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-behavior) in Shell to disable the hamburger in shell.

> The flyout can be accessed through the hamburger icon or by swiping from the side of the screen. However, this behavior can be changed by setting the `Shell.FlyoutBehavior` attached property to one of the `FlyoutBehavior` enumeration members:

- **Disabled** – indicates that the flyout can't be opened by the user.

The following example shows how to disable the flyout:

```
<Shell ...
       FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    ...
</Shell>
```

**Note**:

The `FlyoutBehavior` attached property can be set on `Shell`, `FlyoutItem`, `ShellContent`, and page objects, to override the default flyout behavior.

Answer (score 3):

thank For Junior Jiang - MSFT
I Following his anser
and i forget up date Xamarin form 4.2 to 4.3
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqSlfrsJEns
and add 
`<Shell ...
       FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    ...
</Shell>`